# How to set up Facebook app for Windows Phone 8 app integration

Tags: windows, facebook

I'm building a Windows app. I've created a Facebook app so that I can have an app ID and I'm able to make calls into FB from C#, however the access token expires every hour. Before I write a bunch of code to deal with this, I want to make sure I understand something.

I've read that the expiration of the access token (and other things) depends on how you set up the Facebook app. On the management page for my FB app under the section "Select how your app integrates with Facebook" There are options for website login, FB apps, iOS/Android, etc. But, there's nothing for Windows. Does anyone know which setting I should use for my Windows app?

Thanks.